# AngularJS -Karma testing Jasmine- describe is not defined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, webstorm, karma-jasmine

Just trying to start Angular Testing with Karma. I did install and create my `karma.config`. On CMD when I start my karma, it runs without any problems and opens both of my browsers (Chrome Canary and Firefox)

However it doesn't show Tests on browser. And I don't get any error from karma or anything written on my console.

My File structure and file part of `karma.conf.js`:

[image: Karma.conf.js - file structure]

And in my `.spec.js` file when I write a basic test just to see if it is running properly, in WebStorm it gets underlined. Here is a screenshot for this:

[image: Error message from WebStorm console]

None of the other similar topics on StackOverflow helped me. I am stuck with this error.

What can be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks and sounds like WebStorm is trying to run your tests in a Node.js environment as opposed to a Karma environment.

Try making a Karma run configuration for your `karma.conf.js` file.

More details about making a run configuration can be found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/running-unit-tests-on-karma.html#runConfigurationKarma

Comment: I changed it on my IDE, now it opens the browser aswell, but again when I click on green  triangle next to the line of  'describe' it runs on node.js , 

However when the browser is opened It doesn't show any tests . 

It just says ' Karma v1.6.0 is connected '. How am I suppose to show all the tests on my browser?

Comment: I believe the green triangle will always try to run the tests in Node.js. When the browser opened, it should have run your tests as well. Did see the behavior described in the "Launching Unit Tests" section of the link I posted?

Comment: Yes I did, as I said , it opens my browser , and on karma terminal on webstorm, it says 'Empty test suite'. I feel like the karma doesnt read my files, even tho. I gave the true path for this.Also I still get underlined when I try to write Jasmine on webstorm.

Comment: Ah, whoops, I misunderstood. Are you receiving any warnings when the Karma server starts? If there's a path issue with your configuration, you might see something like `6 04 2017 11:50:52.477:WARN [watcher]: Pattern does not match any file.`

Comment: No, no warnings at all. It is just running without any errors. But there isnt any tests to be shown.